# Subtracting number from bash variable - command not found

Tags: bash, variables

I am new to bash.  I tried to find the answer to this, but couldn't quite find the solution.  I am trying to subtract 86400 from `$yesterday_date`, but I end up with a "command not found" error.

(I know there are other methods of subtracting from a date, but I still want the solution to this problem.)

Script section:

```
yesterday_date=$(date +%s)
echo $yesterday_date
yesterday_date=$($yesterday_date-86400)
echo $yesterday_date
```

Script output:

```
1517335264
./myscript.sh: line 11: 1517335264-86400: command not found
```

What's the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: You need `$((...))`, not `$(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash provides `((...))` for arithmetic operations. You don't have to use `$` before `((..))`.

```
yesterday_date=$(date +%s)
echo "$yesterday_date"
((yesterday_date-=86400))
echo "$yesterday_date"
```

Comment: Please quote your expansions so we're showcasing best practices in our examples here. That would make it `echo "$yesterday_date"`, and thereby robust against, say, `IFS` values with numeric strings. (See also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo)).

Comment: You are so fast. I was going to do the exact edit. In fact, this particular case will be all numeric, quotes are not an absolute requirement, but I get your point about `IFS` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can let date do the math:

```
echo $(date -d "now -86400 seconds" +%s)
1517268350
```

or elimninate the magic number:

```
echo $(date -d "now -1 day" +%s)
1517268356
```

or even more literal:

```
echo $(date -d "yesterday" +%s)
1517268364
```

For fun, there is even a teatime option to the date command. ;)